# Codec problem: Video noise / squares blinking as it play

Tags: video, codec

Its a weird and intermittent problem, it comes and goes with time. I thought I could fix it rebooting, but it seems that is not always. Take a look:

[image]

This noise keeps blinking at the screen the entire movie. If I give up and try again an hour from now, it will be fine... weird!

I have K-Lite Codec Pack installed, in my machine and many others. Its very cool, everything works perfect... but mine is the only one that does it. Do anybody know whats going on?

Edit: Apparently they've just release the very latest version of K-Lite *today* (lol), with some bug fixes. I'll be testing it. Last time I reainstalled K-Lite the problem was gone, but came back again...

Answer (score 1):

Try playing it with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/mirror-geo.php?file=vlc/1.0.1/win32/vlc-1.0.1-win32.exe)

Answer (score 0):

I have found VLC has its fair share of problems too... But the best codec pack I've found has been [the Combined Community Codec Pack](http://cccp-project.net/), which actually *fixes* some codec related issues as it installs. The awesome people over at the CCCP project also have a [troubleshooting guide](http://www.cccp-project.net/wiki/index.php?title=Troubleshooting_Guide) for playback problems -- you could try that.

However, failing different codecs/codec packs, that looks like a GPU overheating problem. I used to have something like that with an ancient GeForce 2 MX card, where the GPU heatsink wasn't correctly in place. Might be worth checking, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [Media Player Classic- Home Cinema](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/). It comes with the K-Lite codec pack, so might be a little more reliable. But really, the first step is to try another player, so +1 to VLC too

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if what your seeing is [tearing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing). [Here](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/AntiTearing.html) is a link to a page on the Media Player Classic - Home Cinema website that discusses it. MPC - HC has a feature that can prevent this (so they say).

You might want to try installing the CCCP. Follow the instructions [here](http://www.cccp-project.net/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page#Latest_CCCP_.28aka._Download_Here.21.29). (Be sure to follow directions about Insurgent and rebooting.) It can install MPC - HC for you, so you can do two in one.

Hope this helps!